# Grouping data on column value

Tags: python, excel, bash, pandas

Hi I have data (in excel and text file as well) like

```
C1   C2    C3
 1    p     a
 1    q     b
 2    r     c
 2    s     d
```

And I want the output like:

```
C1   C2   C3
 1   p,q  a,b
 2   r,s  c,d
```

How can I group the data based on column values.
I am open to anything: any library, any language, any tool
Like python, bash, or even excel?

I think we can do this using pandas in python, but I havent used it before.

Any leads appreciated.

Comment: What did you try with _any library, any language, any tool Like python, bash, or even excel_? Did you make an attempt and fail?

Comment: As of now I didnt try. I am finding the best way to do this

Answer (score 3):

First [`pandas.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) - output is `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Then you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) `join`:

```
df = df.groupby('C1').agg(','.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   C1   C2   C3
0   1  p,q  a,b
1   2  r,s  c,d
```

If more columns in `df` and need filter only `C2` and `C3`:

```
df = df.groupby('C1')['C2','C3'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   C1   C2   C3
0   1  p,q  a,b
1   2  r,s  c,d
```

For save to `excel` file use [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), obviously without `index`:

```
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: this is using pandas?

Comment: exactly, it is pandas solution.

Comment: Hi, this is working. Just that it is not aggregating all the columns. I tried using all the column names explicitly also, but still not working. does the aggregation have some restriction on the datatype of the column? The column which are not getting aggregated are of type: "Date", "ID(varchar)", "Number(some numerical code)" ??Please help me here

Comment: It seems there is problem called http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns - it remove all numeric columns and `join` only string columns. Solution is covert all columns to `string` and then it can works. `df1 = df.astype(str).groupby('C1').agg(','.join).reset_index()`

Comment: But one of it is of type: VARCHAR, can that be a problem too? Also, can I know the datatype of each column in a dataframe??

Comment: You can check it by `print (df.dtypes)` - `dtype` `object` is obviously `string`

Comment: Another issue: When I used a very large file approx of 26M and 6 lakhs rows. Its gave a very wierd behaviour, instaed of aggregating the values of the columns, it aggregated the "heading" of the column wheich were to be aggregated on c1 column. What is the reason? and how can it solved?

Comment: maybe memory problem, how does work  if filter first `1000` rows by `df = df.head(1000)`  ?

Comment: no I am sure its not memory problem. Now it gives following error: "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2668, in aggregate result = self._aggregate_named(func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2786, in _aggregate_named
    output = func(group, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: How can I fix this. Since the file is large how can I find where is it expecting string and found int?

Comment: Hmmm, what return `print df.dtypes` ?  I think the best is convert column which is numeric to string like df['nameofcolumn'] = df['nameofcolumn'].astype(str).