# expected string, int found While using pandas dataframe on a large file

Tags: python, string, pandas, large-data

I have already asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266823/grouping-data-on-column-value/42266842?noredirect=1#comment71703327_42266842), but I am facing a problem when I execute my following code for files with over million rows.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd 
import xlsxwriter


 df = pd.read_excel('full-cust-data-nonconcat.xlsx')

 df  =df.groupby('ORDER_ID')['ASIN'].agg(','.join).reset_index()

 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('PythonExport-Data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
 writer.save()

 print df
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "grouping-data.py", line 9, in <module>
df  =df.groupby('ORDER_ID')['ASIN'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2668, in aggregate
  result = self._aggregate_named(func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2786, in _aggregate_named
   output = func(group, *args, **kwargs)
 TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

Since its a huge file how can I check where is it finding string and getting int?

Is there any way I can convert all this to string first?

Sample Data: (these ids are alpha numeric)

```
ID1 Some_other_id1
ID2 Some_other_id2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a lambda expression in the `agg` function to do the conversion:

```
df.groupby('ORDER_ID')['ASIN'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)).reset_index()
```

---

Or convert the data type before aggregation:

```
df['ASIN'].astype(str).groupby(df['ORDER_ID']).agg(','.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: THANKS IT WORKED. But when I try it on other file with one more string column it gives error as: File "grouping-data.py", line 11, in <module>
    df = df['ASIN'].astype(str).groupby(df['ORDER_ID']).agg(','.join).reset_index()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2059, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2066, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1386, in _get_item_cache
    values = sel

Comment: I am not sure what this is, maybe you can share some of your data that fails the command.